# How far into drupal bootstrap to get global $user

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

If I want to use global $user in a php file outside the drupal system, how far into the boostrap using drupal_boostrap() must I go.  I don't want to use DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL since it sets the HTTP header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION is when the user object is populated.